# Not allowed to load local resource: file:///dist/index.html

Tags: reactjs, electron, package.json, electron-builder

I tried to build my desktop app using electron-builder, the app is built but there is an error **Not allowed to load local resource: file:///dist/index.html**

This is my electron config

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')
let mainWindow = null

app.disableHardwareAcceleration()

// if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) app.quit()

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    // frame: false,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
    },
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  const startUrl =
    process.env.WEB_URL ||
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join('dist/index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true,
    })
  mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl)

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null
  })
  mainWindow.maximize()
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

function handleSquirrelEvent() {
  if (process.argv.length === 1) {
    return false
  }

  const ChildProcess = require('child_process')
  // const path = require('path')

  const appFolder = path.resolve(process.execPath, '..')
  const rootAtomFolder = path.resolve(appFolder, '..')
  const updateDotExe = path.resolve(path.join(rootAtomFolder, 'Update.exe'))
  const exeName = path.basename(process.execPath)

  const spawn = function (command, args) {
    let spawnedProcess, error

    try {
      spawnedProcess = ChildProcess.spawn(command, args, { detached: true })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error')
    }

    return spawnedProcess
  }

  const spawnUpdate = function (args) {
    return spawn(updateDotExe, args)
  }

  const squirrelEvent = process.argv[1]
  switch (squirrelEvent) {
    case '--squirrel-install':
    case '--squirrel-updated':
      // Optionally do things such as:
      // - Add your .exe to the PATH
      // - Write to the registry for things like file associations and
      //   explorer context menus

      // Install desktop and start menu shortcuts
      spawnUpdate(['--createShortcut', exeName])

      setTimeout(app.quit, 1000)
      return true

    case '--squirrel-uninstall':
      // Undo anything you did in the --squirrel-install and
      // --squirrel-updated handlers

      // Remove desktop and start menu shortcuts
      spawnUpdate(['--removeShortcut', exeName])

      setTimeout(app.quit, 1000)
      return true

    case '--squirrel-obsolete':
      // This is called on the outgoing version of your app before
      // we update to the new version - it's the opposite of
      // --squirrel-updated

      app.quit()
      return true
  }
}

// this should be placed at top of main.js to handle setup events quickly
if (handleSquirrelEvent()) {
  // squirrel event handled and app will exit in 1000ms, so don't do anything else
  return
}
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "electron/main.cjs",
  "homepage": "./",
  "author": {
    "name": "myName",
    "email": "example@gmail.com"
  },
  "description": "MyApp",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "dev:staging": "vite --mode staging",
    "build": "tsc && vite build --base=./ --mode development",
    "build:staging": "tsc && vite build --mode staging",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "vitest",
    "coverage": "vitest run --coverage",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "construct": "electron-builder --win"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.194",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "daisyui": "^2.51.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "electron-forge-maker-nsis": "^24.8.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pouchdb": "^8.0.1",
    "pouchdb-find": "^8.0.1",
    "pouchdb-upsert": "^2.2.0",
    "query-string": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-paginate": "^8.1.4",
    "react-pdf": "^7.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
    "react-select": "^5.7.2",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "react-tailwindcss-datepicker": "^1.6.6",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^2.4.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.5",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.5",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.5",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.5",
    "@electron-forge/maker-wix": "^6.0.5",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.5",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/dom-to-image": "^2.6.4",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/pouchdb": "^6.4.0",
    "@types/pouchdb-upsert": "^2.2.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.14",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.53.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.53.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vitest/coverage-c8": "^0.29.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^24.3.0",
    "electron-builder": "^24.6.4",
    "electron-wix-msi": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.35.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.10.2",
    "jsdom": "^21.1.0",
    "less": "^4.1.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "react-select-event": "^5.5.1",
    "sass": "^1.58.3",
    "stylus": "^0.59.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.1.0",
    "vitest": "^0.29.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.myApp.app",
    "productName": "MyApp",
    "directories": {
      "output": "out",
      "buildResources": "dist"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "requestedExecutionLevel": "requireAdministrator"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "removeDefaultUninstallWelcomePage": true,
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
      "runAfterFinish": true,
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "createStartMenuShortcut": true,
      "shortcutName": "MyApp",
      "allowElevation": true
    }
  },
}
```

I already tried to change the directory from "./index/html", "../dist/index.html", and "index.html". None of them working for me. I already look for tutorial online, but nothing works for me. I already ask AI as well but still getting the same error. What is wrong with this?